# Subtracting month in SAS

Tags: date, sas, date-formatting

%let mth1 = '2022-05-01';
how do I get '2022-02-01' from the macro variable?
I was thinking this intnx('month',&mth1.,-3) but this only works in the format of yyyymmdd

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to convert it into a SAS date with `inputn()`, but you will need to remove quotes. `%sysfunc(inputn(&mth1., yymmdd10.))` will convert it to a SAS date so that it can be used in `intnx()`.

```
%let mth1 = 2022-05-01;

%let mth2 = %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(inputn(&mth1., yymmdd10.)), -3), yymmdd10.);

%put &mth2;
```

Output:

```
2022-02-01
```

If you do want the output in single quotes, wrap the function above with `%tslit()`.